# Error with a link action to delete a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a link to delete a record from the database, the link calls a destroy method that is responsible for doing the deletion.
Link:

```rb
<%= link_to "Eliminar el articulo", options = {:action => destroy, :id => @article.id}, html_options = {:method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => '¿Estas seguro?' }, :class => 'btn btn-danger'} %>
```

Routes.rb:

```rb
delete 'articles/:id' => 'articles#destroy'
```

Controller:

```rb
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

To be more concise, I would like to say that I can locate the problem in the link since what fails is `:action => destroy` but if I remove the link, what it does is go to the same page instead of delete the record.

The error: undefined local variable or method `destroy' for #ActionView::Base:0x000000000395d0

The text is translated using Google Translate. To see the original question [click here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/526417/error-al-crear-un-link-to)

Comment: Post the stack trace please and what version of rails are you using?

Comment: @jamesc Rails version is 7.0.2.3 and ruby version is 3.1.1p18

Answer (score 1):

> The error: undefined local variable or method `destroy' for #ActionView::Base:0x000000000395d0

`destroy` variable is not defined in the view... you should use a symbol instead (`:action => :destroy`)

```rb
<%= link_to "Eliminar el articulo", options = {:action => :destroy, :id => @article.id}, html_options = {:method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => '¿Estas seguro?' }, :class => 'btn btn-danger'} %>
```

However, I suggest to use the route helpers:

```
  delete 'articles/:id' => 'articles#destroy', as: :article
  # or user rails resources
  # resources :articles, only: [:destroy]
```

```
<%= link_to "Eliminar el articulo", article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: Does nothing, redirects to the route you are on

Comment: Keep redirecting to the path you are on

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 = form_tag(article_path(@article), method: :delete, remote: true) do
   = button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-danger') do
     = content_tag(:strong, 'Delete')
```

Comment: Gives an error: undefined method `article_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000004e1b0>

Comment: Just add 'resources :articles'  in your routes.rb file

Comment: How do I put it in the routes.rb file. Method to use (get, post, delete, ...), which route to send it to and which controller method to use. As far as I know, this is the format ```delete 'articles/:id' => 'articles#destroy'```